# Any good resources for learning programming GPU level operations?

Tags: c++, gpu

I want to be able to improve my lower level device specific programming abilities to assist in future endeavors. Examples would be learning to write custom tensorflow operations in C++ optimized to work on GPUS. Does anyone know good resources to find tutorials showing which packages to use for which devices and etc.?

An approach other than just reading source and replicating until understanding would be nice.

Comment: take a look at [cuda toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit) by nvidia